# How to access component instannce with in full calander event handler using angular 2.0

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using following plugins for calendar:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ap-angular2-fullcalendar.

**Any help will appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ViewChild or @ViewChildren to get access to the calendar component.
i personally use ViewChildren as it can handle change events effectively and render the calendar on go.

In your component import the fullcalendar as

```
import { Options } from 'fullcalendar';
import {CalendarComponent} from 'angular2-fullcalendar/src/calendar/calendar';
```

and get a refference to the calendarComponent as

```
@ViewChildren('mycal') calendar: QueryList<CalendarComponent>
```

and my html would look like

```
<div class="ui red segment" *ngIf="dataAvailable">
                <angular2-fullcalendar [options]="calOptions" id="mycal" #mycal></angular2-fullcalendar>
 </div>
```

Now i can access the calendar and perform action.For example to refetch the events and refresh the calendar i would do

```
this.calendar.forEach(div => 
  {

    div.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    div.fullCalendar('removeEventSources');
    div.fullCalendar('addEventSource',this.events);

  })
```

Hope it helps